# How to correctly pass inequality or range to dplyr::case_when

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I am unsuccessfully trying to create levels of a given variable using dplyr::case_when involving intervals.

**#preparing sample data**

```
mtmodel <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)
mtcars$Low <- predict(mtmodel, newdata = mtcars, interval = "confidence")[,2]
mtcars$High <- predict(mtmodel, newdata = mtcars, interval = "confidence")[,3]
mtcars$Mean <- predict(mtmodel, newdata = mtcars, interval = "confidence")[,1]
new_mtcars<-gather(mtcars, "Variable", "value", Low:Mean)
```

**#creating groups using dplyr::case_when**

```
#does not work
library(tidyverse)
new_new_mtcars<-new_mtcars %>%
       mutate(grouping = case_when (
       min(new_mtcars$wt) <= new_mtcars$wt<= mean(new_mtcars$wt)+0.99 ~ "group1",
       new_mtcars$wt >= max(new_mtcars$wt) - 0.5  ~ "group2"))
```

**#R returns this error message and does not do the job as intended**

```
Error: unexpected '<=' in:
"           mutate(grouping = case_when (
               min(new_mtcars$wt) <= new_mtcars$wt<="

Error: unexpected ')' in "           
new_mtcars$wt >= max(new_mtcars$wt) - 0.5  ~ "group2")"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
new_new_mtcars <- new_mtcars %>%
  mutate(grouping = case_when(
    min(wt) <= wt & wt <= mean(wt) + 0.99 ~ "group1",
    wt >= max(wt) - 0.5  ~ "group2"
  ))
```

You don't need to reference your data frame inside the pipe after the first reference. Furthermore, `min(wt) <= wt <= mean(wt) + 0.99` will always throw an error as you always need to have two variables per operator, so you need to specify `wt <= mean(wt) + 0.99` as another condition.

An exception would be if you'd use something like `between`, where you first state the variable which is in-between, and then the lower and upper bounds, like this:

```
new_new_mtcars <- new_mtcars %>%
  mutate(grouping = case_when(
    between(wt, min(wt), mean(wt) + 0.99) ~ "group1",
    wt >= max(wt) - 0.5  ~ "group2"
  ))
```

Comment: Great, @arg0naut! The solution with between is better because it works not only with my sample data but also with my actual data. Thanks for this very helpful solution.

Comment: You're welcome! Normally it should work both ways, but glad at least one helped!